# ROS Answers SE migration: ROS over QNX

Tags: ros, real-time

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Has anyone tried to use ROS over QNX?

I would like to use ROS topics to export data (i.e. joints) from an existing system that runs over QNX.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/54353/ros-over-qnx/) by [dgerod](https://answers.ros.org/users/1843/dgerod/) on ROS Answers with karma: 113 on 2013-02-05

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As far as found online, there have been some people who tried, but no success has been reported. Some references:

- An [email thread](http://code.ros.org/lurker/message/20090819.051336.8e44e6de.en.html) in 2009.
- `realtime` ROS [discussion in May 2013](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/ros-sig-embedded/thSi3CPK3kA)

I'm about to look into porting `catkin` into `QNX`, since I have received a kind of strong interest toward enabling `ROS`, or at least build system, on `QNX`.

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2013-06-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dgerod](https://answers.ros.org/users/1843/dgerod/) on 2013-06-05**:
Good. I am interested in your progress...

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2013-07-24**:
As in [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ros-sig-embedded/cak1-QNevgo) thread, `catkin` is ported on QNX, and there's also a progress in getting ROS run there too. It seems, however, to have stopped progressing at rosdep at the moment.